# Deleting xml:base attribute from an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm currently having trouble deleting a troublesome attribute from my Xdocument's root node: **xml:base**.

My Xdocument **currentDoc**:

```
<root xml:base="texthere">
    <child/>
</root>
```

I looked at the documentation about xml:base here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/.

I'm having trouble in my C# code to get rid of this because this **xml:** prefix doesn't have a declaration like other namespace prefixes.

This is what I have which isn't working:

```
currentDoc.Root.Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "xml" namespace is defined:

```
currentDoc.Root.Attributes(XNamespace.Xml + "base").Remove();
```